# Combining "find" with function in Beaitufulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get list of the tags which are, CTC_3D_Printer, ctc_prusa_i3_pro_b, CTC_Upgrades from the following html source code

```
 html = """
<div class="content_stack">
    <h2 class="section-header justify">
        Tags

            </h2>


    <div class="thing-detail-tags-container">
        <div class="taglist">
                    <a href="/tag:CTC_3D_Printer">CTC_3D_Printer</a>
                    <a href="/tag:ctc_prusa_i3_pro_b">ctc_prusa_i3_pro_b</a>
                    <a href="/tag:CTC_Upgrades">CTC_Upgrades</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>



    <div class="content_stack">
        <h2 class="section-header">
            Design Tools
        </h2>

        <div class="taglist">
                    <span>Tinkercad</span>
                </div>
    </div>
"""
```

Normally I would use:

```
tags = soup.find("h2", string = "Tags").findNextSibling()
```

to get the tags. However as there is extra space surrounding the Tags I can not use it. Tags are not always the first element in comes right after the `<div class="content_stack">`. How could I solve my problem, by combining "find" with some pre-defined function?

Comment: As a side note: Why are you using `findNextSibling`? Are you using BS3, or are you trying to learn BS4 from a tutorial or book or sample code written for BS3? BS3 has been abandoned for over half a decade (and even in BS3, 3.2 provided the BS4-style names to make porting easier).

Comment: oh, what should I use instead findNextSiblings? Actually I learned BS by looking at other's scripts so ...

Comment: Look at newer scripts instead of 6-year-old ones. Or, better, look at the examples in the docs.

Comment: What was your question really @edyvedy13? Did you not try to get `CTC_3D_Printer, ctc_prusa_i3_pro_b, CTC_Upgrades ` these tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [Kinds of filters](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters) in the docs, you just write a function (that takes a BS tag object and returns true if it's a match), and pass it to `find`.

Their example is a function that finds only tags with a `class` but without an `id`:

```
def has_class_but_no_id(tag):
    return tag.has_attr('class') and not tag.has_attr('id')
```

For your case, you just want to do an `in` check on the text:

```
h2 = soup.find('h2', string=lambda s: 'Tags' in s)
```

… or maybe:

```
h2 = soup.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='h2' and 'Tags' in tag.string)
```